# With regard to design patterns, why not just extend the Entity Framework classes with the business logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got an ASP.NET MVC application and am looking at ways to improve readability, testing, etc.  Currently, much of the business logic is in the controller and I would like to move this to another location.

Here's one idea I have been looking at using: Entity framework creates entity classes for me (e.g. Product, Customer).  Why not just create partial classes to store the business logic?  Here is an example:

```
public partial class Product()
{
   public static List<Product> GetGreenProducts()
   {
       using(MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
       {
           return db.Product.where(p => p.Color == "green").ToList();
       }
   }

}
```

Then, in the controller, I can do this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult GreenProducts()
   {
       return View(Product.GetGreenProducts());
   }
}
```

This approach seems 1) Very simple 2) Very clean 3) would allow for easy unit testing.

I think this is a relevant pattern.  Can anyone identify any problems with this, or other thoughts?

Comment: Because business logic doesn't belong at the EF level any more than it belongs in a controller. You should add at least 1 other layer.  Most enterprise apps will have many other layers.  Services, business logic, DAO's and various supporting patterns.

Comment: myProductInstance.UpdateLastModified();  (this UpdateLastModified method is in a partial class) seems more correct than using a separate ProductService class:  ProductService.UpdateLastModified(myProductInstance);

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions being asked here:

1. Why not extend EF classes with business log (as opposed to Controllers)?

Simple.  Because business logic should not be coupled to EF anymore than it should be coupled to Controllers.

2. Essentially (and this is my interpretation of the OP's comment), why not put CRUD operations in EF as opposed to Controllers.  Sample method given: `UpdateLastModified` does it belong in EF or a seperate Service?

`UpdateLastModified` is already far too coupled an example to begin with.  You should not create a method to update a column on an entity.  Do you also need `UpdateCreatedBy`, `UpdateName`, `UpdateId`?  I sure hope not.  EF gives you all the tools necessary to perform such trivial tasks.

The `ProductService` should be concerned with middle tier concerns, whatever they may be.  Things like projecting the `ProductEntity` -> `ProductDao` and what have you.  `ProductService.UpdateLastModified` should not exist.